# If a function f: R to R has the property that $f(x)/x^n$ tends to zero as x tends to zero, does it follow that f is infinitely differentiable at 0?

Tags: real-analysis

If a differentiable function f: R to R has the property that $f(x)/x^n$ tends to zero as x tends to zero for every positive integer n, does it follow that f is infinitely differentiable at 0?

I know you have to find a counterexample but I am struggling to find a function that satisfies the first property alone!!

Answer (score 0):

A trivial example is $f(x)=0$ if $x\ne0$, $f(0)=1$. But probably you want a more interesting example, like
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}\sin\bigl(e^{1/x^2}\bigr) & x\ne0,\\
0 & x=0.\end{cases}
$$
$f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, but $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Funny how our answers turned to be that similar=)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say f has to be differentiable!!

Comment: The second example is differentiable, but not $C^1$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a function $$g(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x=0,\\\exp(-1/x^2),&x\ne 0\end{cases}$$

It satisfies your condition, yet it is not continuous at zero, let alone differentiable.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say f has to be differentiable!!